Does the category $\mathbf{Hilb}_m$ contain directed colimits?
I'm reading the paper "Hilbert spaces and $C^*$-Algebras are not finitely concrete" by Lieberman et al. (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1908.10200). When discussing the category $\mathbf{Hilb}_m$ of complex Hilbert spaces with injective linear contractions as morphisms, they say

We observe in passing that Hilbm is an $\aleph_1$-accessible category with
directed colimits.

I'm somewhat new to category theory, but does "with directed colimits" mean with all directed colimits--and if so, can someone explain why this is true? Intuitively, I would think that by restricting the morphisms to injective linear contractions (as opposed to $\mathbf{Hilb}$, which has all linear contractions), one would be able to construct a counterexample--I was struggling to do so for awhile.

Yes, it means all directed colimits.

This is false. Consider the following directed system indexed by $\mathbb{N}$: $H_n = H$ for some fixed nontrivial Hilbert space $H$, and the connecting map $f_{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\text{Id}_H$ ($\frac{1}{2}$ can be replaced by any positive constant smaller than $1$). There is no colimit for this system in $\mathbf{Hilb}_m$, for, suppose $K$ with morphisms $f_n: H = H_n \to K$ is the colimit, then for any $h \in H$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $f_1(h) = f_n \circ f_{1n}(h) = f_n(2^{-(n-1)}h)$, so as $f_n$ is a contraction, $\|f_1(h)\| = \|f_n(2^{-(n-1)}h)\| \leq 2^{-(n-1)}\|h\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, $f_1$ is the zero map, contradicting the specification that all morphisms are injective.

Not that I'm disagreeing with you but this is a surprisingly elementary mistake for a paper with at least one well-known category theorist's name on it. Maybe the authors were only thinking about directed systems where the maps are isometries.

@QiaochuYuan That might be the case. The colimit certainly exists when the connecting maps are isometries. Or maybe they were thinking about vector spaces for intuition? After all, directed colimits do exist in the category of vector spaces and injective linear maps.

They mention their key proof doesn’t work for the category of isometries, though, and the whole paper relies on the result for Hilb_m, so there’s something important to be fixed. I think you may be able to salvage the paper by rewriting the claim to say that Hilb_m has directed colimits of isometries—they only seem to use the directed colimit of the lattice of subspace inclusions, and then the technical work with non-isometric inclusions happens with finitely many spaces at a time. I’m just not sure whether the uniformization theorem might fail to apply.

Thank you, this is really helpful! I think I had a similar example in mind but had trouble formulating it. I thought I was going crazy when I was reading that paper.
